# Why is this for loop not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

What is the exactly difference between:

```
<p id="test"></p>

<script>

function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
        if(arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = findMax(32, 133, 83, 163);

</script>
```

and:

```
<p id="test"></p>

<script>

function findMax() {
    var i = 0;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(; i < arguments.length ; i++) {
        if(arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = findMax(32, 133, 83, 163);

</script>
```

Maybe I have missed some classes but the first one outputs 163, as it should, while the second one outputs 0. The console says

> SyntaxError: return not in function
>
> return max;

Why does the second one return the lowest value, while the first one returns highest value?

Comment: In second one you missed "i" here in for-->  for(; i < arguments.length ; i++)

Comment: Also: you either forgot a curly brace or you have an extra curly brace

Comment: in the second one you never set i to an initial value

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: By editing your question, you've removed the issue...your whole problem was that you were missing a curly brace

Comment: I didn't remove the issue. Check again my question at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: They both return the same value here: https://jsfiddle.net/4kzkf96s/

Comment: @super11 now both outputs the same value for me at chrome

Comment: your question makes no sense, now. the only difference is the assignment of `i`. it is either inside of the for initialization part, or at the declaration. the rest is the same.

Comment: after testing I get 163 on both scripts

Answer (score 3):

> while the second one outputs 0.

You didn't initialize **i** to `0`.

Which means i was undefined, and `undefined + 1` is `NaN`.

> SyntaxError: return not in function

You missed a curly brace after for-loop, so the return statement went outside the function definition

```
function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(i = 0; i < arguments.length ; i++)
    {//this was missed
        if(arguments[i] > max) 
        {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for the 2nd one you forget the opening bracket `{` and initial value `i=0`

You can also simply use `Math.max()`

Answer (score 1):

in second you are missing a `{`, try:

```
function findMax() {
    var i;
    var max = -Infinity;
    for(; i < arguments.length ; i++) {
        if(arguments[i] > max) {
            max = arguments[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```